# How do I populate MongoDB with my CDN Links?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, amazon-s3, cdn

I have a JSON file, and I have some audio file in each entry.

```
{
        {
         audio: '~/audios/1.mp3'
         info: 'some other info'
        },
        {
         audio: '~/audios/2.mp3'
         info: 'some other info'
        },
        {
         audio: '~/audios/3.mp3'
         info: 'some other info'
    }
}
```

Now I would like to put all of this stuff in my MongoDB database (instead of using this JSON). In the very end my app will be using some service to store the mp3 files on some super-efficient server I guess, so I would need to save their proper links in my MongoDB. So I guess I will have links like `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/bla/data/audio1.mp3` (for example) - But how do I generate these links and pop them into my MongoDB database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Just upload your audio to your CDN. It should generate the links for you. You can save these to MongoDB by interfacing directly with the Mongo shell or using the Mongoose ORM. If users are going to be uploading music to your app directly, you will probably be using some external API to upload files. For example, if you wanted to upload Images to the Imgur API, you would send data to their API endpoints for image uploads and their API would automatically return a link to your image. You would need to write a callback function that checks whether the image upload went correctly - if all went well and you don't need to throw an error, you would have a method written in your callback to create a new document in MongoDB/Mongoose to save that link, following a schema that makes it logically possible to retrieve the location/uploader (also saving a reference to the user who uploaded it, for example)

You would also probably be using HTML's  to handle this, if it's a web app

Alternatively, you can set up your own methods on your back-end server for storing and retrieving file uploads, hosting on Amazon will give you a lot of bandwidth to work with.